# Delete files from s3 bucket based on names listed in file using cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

I'm trying to delete multiple (like: thousands) of files from Amazon S3 bucket.
I have a file names listed in a file like so:

```
name1.jpg
name2.jpg
...
name2020201.jpg
```

I tried following solution:

```
aws s3 rm s3://test-bucket --recursive --exclude "*" --include "data/*.*"
```

from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46246151/delete-files-from-folder-in-s3-bucket) but --include only takes one arg.
I tried to get hacky and list names like `--include "name1.jpg"` but this does not work either.

This approach does not work as well:

```
aws s3 rm s3://test-bucket < file.txt
```

Can you help?

Comment: did you tried this `aws s3 rm s3://test-bucket --recursive --exclude "*" --include "data/*.jpg" `

Comment: Yes, I actually did it without "=" sign, which is correct and I will fix it. But that example does not solve the problem in question, the answer does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following approach is actually much faster since my first answer took ages to complete.

My first approach was to delete one line at a time using `rm` command. This is not efficient. After around 15h (!) it deleted only around 40.000 records, which was 1/5 of total.

[This approach](https://www.preining.info/blog/2020/10/deleting-many-files-from-an-s3-bucket/) by Norbert Preining is waaay faster. As he explains, it uses s3api method called **delete-objects** which can bulk delete objects in storage. This method takes a json object as an argument. To parse list of file names into JSON object required, this script uses JSON preprocessor called **jq** ([read more here](https://github.com/stedolan/jq)). The script takes 500 records per iteration.

```
cat file-with-names |  while mapfile -t -n 500 ary && ((${#ary[@]})); do
        objdef=$(printf '%s\n' "${ary[@]}" | ./jq-win64.exe -nR '{Objects: (reduce inputs as $line ([]; . + [{"Key":$line}]))}')
        aws s3api --no-cli-pager  delete-objects --bucket BUKET --delete "$objdef"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out with this simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash  
set -e  
while read line  
do  
   aws s3 rm s3://test-bucket/$line
done <files.txt
```

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62795817/how-do-i-download-files-with-aws-cli-based-on-a-list?rq=1)
Answer is: delete one at a time!